# How I can compile a Java class that refers another Java class in the same directory?

Tags: java, tomcat, terminal, package, javabeans

I'm doing a web application in Tomcat, and the only bug that's the only step to run my app is to compile my JavaClass in the Terminal Console. So the problem is that:i have 2 classes, User.java and loginDB.java.

1. I put "javac User.java" and it compiles
2. Then, i try to compile loginDB.java but, since I have to use the User class as an object and its methods, I have tried to refer to the User class with 'package beans;' (beans is the folder where both files are located) but when I try to compile the User class via the terminal, it tells me

[image: Error by compile Java class by refering another Java Class and its methods]

I do not find a logical solution on how to solve this problem, because I cannot use a class and its methods despite being in the same folder or in this case in the same package

Comment: Does `javac LoginDB.java User.java` work? You should be able to compile both files at once.

Comment: Are you importing `User` class to `LoginDB`?

Comment: [Please post text, not images.](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: I encourage you to use an IDE, eg IntelliJ, and a build tool, eg gradle.